# Setting up server cache on Apache 2.4.7 (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, caching, apache2.4

What is the best way to set up server caching on Apache 2.4?

I have searched the internet and found a few resources and tutorials specific to Apache 2.2 - but apache have dropped modules since 2.2 and renamed others. Specifically, I would like to set up caching on my Ubuntu environment using the equivalent of Apache 2.2 "mod_cache", "mod_disk_cache" and "mod_mem_cache".

For example, existing documentation refers to enabling:
mod_cache, mod_disk_cache and mod_mem_cache

In my /etc/apache2/mods-available directory and the mods there that seem relevant are:
cache and cache_disk (notice different naming conventions), also there is nothing even similar to mem_cache (there are other references to socache etc but those are different)

Here's a good resource that's helped me get this far [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/caching-with-apaches-mod_cache-on-debian-lenny) ([and another](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-content-caching-using-apache-modules-on-a-vps)). The apache documentation does a decent job of explaining what the modules do but not HOW to set them up.

UPDATE:
I'm running Ubuntu 14.01.1 LTS
Found confirmation that apache removed mem_cache in 2.4 - still looking for any up to date cache resources/ tutorials though

UPDATE2:
It seems there are actually no resources out there specifically for configuring caching on apache 2.4, so here are the steps I've taken so far which may help future searches:

```
#Check which modules are available    
ls /etc/apache2/mods-available
#Enable cache modules
sudo a2enmod cache
sudo a2enmod cache_disk
#restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart

#edit the cache_disk.conf file
sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/cache_disk.conf
```

uncomment the line CacheEnable /disk so that the conf file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>

        # cache cleaning is done by htcacheclean, which can be configured in
        # /etc/default/apache2
        #
        # For further information, see the comments in that file,
        # /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian, and the htcacheclean(8)
        # man page.

        # This path must be the same as the one in /etc/default/apache2
        CacheRoot /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk

        # This will also cache local documents. It usually makes more sense to
        # put this into the configuration for just one virtual host.
        CacheEnable disk /


    # The result of CacheDirLevels * CacheDirLength must not be higher than
    # 20. Moreover, pay attention on file system limits. Some file systems
    # do not support more than a certain number of inodes and
    # subdirectories (e.g. 32000 for ext3)
    CacheDirLevels 2
    CacheDirLength 1

</IfModule>
```

restart apache again for changes to take effect

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Next we need to make sure when the cache fills up it's cleaned using an apache utility and configuring htcacheclean:

```
aptitude install apache2-utils
#cleans the cache every 30 min and makes sure it doesnt get bigger than 100M
htcacheclean -d30 -n -t -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_disk_cache -l 100M -i
#configure htclean to start every time the server restarts
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
#add the following lines before the exit 0 line
[...]
/usr/sbin/htcacheclean -d30 -n -t -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_disk_cache -l 100M -i
[...]
```

...And that's as far as I've managed to get so far.

UPDATE 3:
I've tried testing in a browser using a new file test.php:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=300");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time()."<br>";
?>
```

I should be able to hit return on the url a 2nd time and the timestamp should not have changed, but this isn't the case so I think I've missed something/ not completed this.

Comment: Note: htcacheclean -d30 -n -t -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_disk_cache -l 100M -i       SHOULD BE      htcacheclean -d30 -n -t -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 100M -i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problems but finally found a helping tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Don't foprget that caching does not work if Contrnt-length is unknown.

Answer (score 6):

Above article is almost perfect, also this one might help: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/caching.htm

But still you'll probably face problems like "CACHE MISS, ATTEMMPTING ENTITY SAVE" or no caching at all.

First of all it seems caching does not work if Content-length is unknown.
So if caching is not working for your script, turn on cache headers and check all headers first.
Otherwise you might get always X-Cache-Detail: "cache miss: attempting entity save".

Easiest way how to determine if cache is working is probably:

```
curl -s -D - http://xxx.yyy.com/yorsite | head -n 15
```

Then you see if cache hit occurs after second try and all other headers sent. Adjust -n parameter to how many lines your headers have in particular case.

Of course setting logging for mod_cache might help.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %{cache-status}e %>s %b" cache
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mod_cache.log cache
```

Setting proper session_cache_limiter is important (to "" or "public", "must_revalidate", try it...)

To summarize common issues with cachig (for Apache 2.4.7) are:

- missing CacheRoot in VirtualHost section
- missing setting for CacheQuickHandler off (if you use mod_rewrite mapping to rewritten URLs won't work probably or caching won't work at all)
- unknown or missing Content-Length header (be aware, simple PHP script will send it, more complex might not)
- missing session_cache_limiter("") or set to "private" - causes to send "no_store", "no-cache" in Cache-Control header

So for caching of dynamic content (php etc) you probably need to do:

```
ob_start();
...your code...
$PageContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Set header for content length
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($PageContent));

// Send the full content
print $PageContent;
```

Then, you can enjoy boost of performance :)

Finally working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName devel.artikul.cz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx.com.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx.com.access.log combined

        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %{cache-status}e %>s %b" cache
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mod_cache.log cache

        CacheQuickHandler off
        CacheRoot /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk

        CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
        CacheLock on
        CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
        CacheLockMaxAge 5
        CacheDetailHeader on

        #example disk caching
        CacheEnable disk "/xxxx.php"
        CacheEnable disk "/blog"
        CacheEnable disk "/content"
        CacheHeader on

        CacheDefaultExpire 600
        CacheMaxExpire 86400
        CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5
        CacheMaxFileSize 1000000
        CacheMinFileSize 1

        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"

        Header merge Cache-Control public
        FileETag All

</VirtualHost>
```